Downloaded file from angular app is corrupt
I have a template file stored in the parent (shell)app assets/template folder of my Angular App. I used the below line in the HTML file of the child app to download the template.


<a href="/assets/template/sample.xlsx" download="sample.xlsx"> Download the Sample Template file </a>



The File gets downloaded successfully and gets opened with no issue in localhost:80XX. But from another environment like DEV, the file gets downloaded but when trying to open it I get the "File is corrupt and cannot be opened." error message. Please let me know what I missed and thank you in advance.

if you've already confirmed that the file is not corrupt on the server-side, I would check the returned mime-type.  (it should show in response headers?)  It should be something like "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

I checked in the developer tool and the Network tab has 2 Type files (xhr and document) when I check each file contentType it shows "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". I am not sure why it created two Types and I think that might be why I get the issue.

xhr suggests this isn't a standard link, but a javascript request (XHTML Response Header).  Is there any JS code that handles this click?   What is the backend and what does it return?  Not sure it should be returning a document either.

You might try just opening the file in a text editor.  (it might give you a clue... say if, you're receiving a web page/error instead of a binary file)
